# Function ASP.NET uses to generate Session ID?

Tags: asp.net, session, sessionid

Does ASP.NET expose the underlying function it uses to generate session IDs?  I want to generate a session token for use in a web service, but it will not be put in the Set-Cookie header.  If ASP.NET already has a function I can use to generate a session ID this will save me from having to roll my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is your friend:

SessionIDManager.CreateSessionID()

```
internal static string Create(ref RandomNumberGenerator randgen)
{
    if (randgen == null)
    {
        randgen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    }
    byte[] data = new byte[15];
    randgen.GetBytes(data);
    return Encode(data);
}
```

Comment: This was similar to how I was going to roll it on my own... comforting to know I wasn't far off.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`?

Comment: As I understand it, GUIDs are good for uniqueness but they are bad  as a security token because they are not random enough to prevent guessing.

Comment: i'd like to see somebody guess a guid!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what ASP.Net uses under the hood, but you should be able to use [System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) to come up with a unique value.