# Are ServiceStack session ids secure enough?

Tags: .net, security, guid, servicestack

From what I understand, when using ServiceStack's [Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) you'd typically authenticate at the start of a session and then mark the session on the server side as authenticated. Subsequent web service requests will use that session id and not require re-authentication. (Please correct me if I'm wrong so far).

Generation of new session ids is performed using Guid.NewGuid() in [SessionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/SessionExtensions.cs#L75), which [doesn't generate cryptographically fantastic values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6267578/8479). Is there any reason not to switch to use cryptographically secure values, e.g. using [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228085/function-asp-net-uses-to-generate-session-id)?

UPDATE:

Actually, after thinking about it a bit further, ASP.NET doesn't use its Session Id to confirm that the requestor is authenticated. It uses a FormsAuthenticationTicket which has been encrypted with a machine key and hashed ([here's a nice description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) of the process for ASP.NET 2.0).

I'm not a security dude so I don't know what implication this has if you were to compare the level of security provided by ASP.NET Forms Auth and that provided by a random value. I suppose it all comes down to key and data lengths... but also the time required to mount a brute-force attack on Forms Authentication is probably much higher as it doesn't require just trying a whole heap of random numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) uses the standard HTTP approach of Authenticating + Set session cookie to setup an authenticated session for subsequent requests, which is a common approach across all web frameworks.

Although I've never heard of a vulnerability in .NET from being able to predict and reverse-engineer a GUID, [it appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6902739/85785) that ASP.NET's own SessionId is not as strong as a Guid (2^120 vs 2^128 bits of entropy). But given it's not truly random we'll change ServiceStack's implementation to use a truly random identifier in the next release.

Comment: Just realised that ASP.NET doesn't use SessionIds for authentication but rather encrypted & hashed FormsAuthenticationTickets. Any thoughts on comparison of security? Not wanting to be a pain but this is important for us to be able to comfortably choose this framework.

Comment: The quickest way to get something done is to just send a pull-request for it. Otherwise it'll have to wait till we have the free time to do it. I'll look at getting this in before this weekends release (v3.9.38+) - but no promises.

Comment: FYI v3.9.38+ of ServiceStack was updated to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider as seen [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4235f0b11ff6ee9a6f49c49edacb4363684291e2)

Comment: Awesome!! Did you go down to 120-bits just to be consistent with ASP.NET SessionIds?

Comment: Yeah, no strong reason to be different. So just in-case SessionIds ever need to be compatible with existing ASP.NET SessionId field in future.